# Payment form with Internationalization

Tags: commerce, i18n-l10n

I have a simple form which should be able to accept payment via Paypal. The form(site) will support multiple languages and depending on the language, it should change the currency appropriately after applying forex conversion.

I don't want to use drupal commerce since it's too bulky for my requirements. I was thinking if possible what set of modules be used to accomplish this, e.g. webform, paypal webform, which internationalization/localization plugins and so on?

Comment: _I don't want to use drupal commerce since it's too bulky_ Have you actually tried Drupal Commerce? It's not bulky at all. The base functionality has a relatively small footprint, and you can build literally any type of shopping experience with it. Don't dismiss it because there are a lot of included modules or contributed modules - you only enable what you need, and it's the best commerce solution for Drupal by quite some distance

Comment: I have tried it and as you said it's a bunch of modules. If I am not wrong, it comes with a shopping cart and I am not sure if it can be eliminated since this form doesn't need a shopping cart, just a one click payment via Paypal.

Comment: The shopping cart is a module - if you don't need it, don't enable it :)

Comment: Alright. Can you build forms using it with multiple field types just like webforms or webform need to be integrated with it?

Answer (score 1):

The [Webform Paypal](https://drupal.org/project/webform_paypal) module sends the user to Paypal to complete a payment whenever they submit a webform containing the component on your site.

> - This module does not directly integrate with Paypal's APIs.
> - This module allows a site user to generate a Paypal 'Buy Now', 'Add to
>     Cart' or 'Donate' button and replace their form's submit button with
>     that button.
> - You can manually keep track of the payment status on individual
>     submissions.

Comment: It was obviously my first choice but it doesn't support multiple currencies.

Comment: I think this https://drupal.org/project/payment_webform  will support multi currency, but you need to test it